# ActiveState restrictions for a company?

Tags: python, licensing, activepython

I recently learned about [ActivePython](http://www.activestate.com/activepython/downloads) as a convenient way of quickly getting Python up and running on a variety of platforms.

I am employed by a private software company in the US and was wondering: what are the implications of downloading and using ActivePython for some of our projects?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about licensing or legal issues, not programming or software development. [See here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/274963/questions-about-licensing/274964#274964) and [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/139804/can-licensing-questions-ever-be-on-topic) for details, and the [help] for more.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The download description says:

> Download ActivePython Community Edition free binaries for your development projects and internal deployments.

That implies you can use it for both developing and deploying internal projects, and for developing but not deploying external projects. But that's certainly not a legally binding implication, and it's a little vague (for example, what if you deploy an internal project that runs an external software-as-a-service system?). Nor is the interpretation of myself or anyone else you're going to find on SO going to be of any value.

If you don't trust yourself to read and figure out http://www.activestate.com/activepython/license-agreement, you need to have a lawyer do so, under circumstances that allow you to rely on their advice.

Or, maybe, contact ActiveState and ask them.

But really, no answer from anyone else is useful.